# Ionic hrefs not opening in Android

Tags: javascript, html, json, ionic-framework

I have been working on an app that uses JSON data from a server. In this JSON data there is an object that is made up of HTML, which often has an URL in it. And I also have an object that is 'just' an URL which I load into a button which should open the URL when clicked. The problem is, however, that when I click the URL's in the Ionic View app the URL's will open inside the app itself. But when I click the URL's in the standalone build on Android both these URL's don't work. What I try to accomplish is that both these URL's open in the system browser when clicked. But I can't seem to find out why this doesn't work

I do have the Cordova script in my index.html, and I also have the InAppBrowser plugin installed from Cordova.

This is the button:

```
<a class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-model="button" ng-click="openUrl({{vacature.url}})"> Sollicitatielink </a>
```

This is the function in my controllers.js:

```
$scope.openUrl = function(url) {

    window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');

};
```

This is the HTML in the JSON data:

```
<a href="url_here" target="_blank">via our website.</a>
```

I was wondering if you guys could help me with why this doesn't work. Could it be that I did not implement the plugin correctly, and if so, how could I do this properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `<a ng-href="url_here" target="_blank">via our website.</a>` ? P.S. Check the brackets at `ng-click="openUrl({vacature.url}})"`. There you can use `ui-sref="openUrl({vacature.url})"`

Comment: I did try that yes, but the problem is that that only works in the browser when testing with _ionic serve_, this does not work in the Android app itself... Also, thanks for the tip! Typing mistake.. :/

Comment: Try this `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">via our website.</a>`. Do you get any errors in console when testing on device?

Comment: I'm getting the error:
_Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 18 of the expression [window.open(...._
It seems like the syntax error has to do with the fact that the URL has https: in it....

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why my URL's were not opening when clicking the button. This is the code I now use for it to work properly.

This is the button:

```
<button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="openUrl('{{vacature.url}}')"> Sollicitatielink </button>
```

This is the function:

```
$scope.openUrl = function(extUrl) {

    window.open(extUrl, '_system');

};
```

**Edit**

The URL's in the JSON HTML data are now working because of this code:

```
<a href="url_here" target="_blank">via our website.</a>
```

Is now changed to this:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.open('url_here', '_system')">via our website.</a>
```

And now all the hrefs in the Ionic app work!

Answer (score 0):

this is how I implemented the plug-in and works for me:

```
    <button class="button button-block button-stable" ng-click="openInBrowser('https://www.google.com')">
        GOOGLE
    </button>
```

then in the JS

```
myApp.controller('NameCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaInAppBrowser', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaInAppBrowser){

            $scope.openInBrowser = function(extUrl){

                $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
                    var options = {
                        location: 'yes',
                        clearcache: 'yes',
                        toolbar: 'yes'
                      };

                    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(extUrl, '_system', options)
                    .then(function(event) {
                      // success
                    })
                    .catch(function(event) {
                      // error
                    });               

                }); // $ionicPlatform.ready
            };//--------------------------------------
        }]);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when using your code: _Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column..._ Any idea why that is?

Comment: sounds like an AngularJS error, does your page with an empty controller work? if yes then start from there and then add from the code above inside your controller.

Comment: I have been able to figure out why the error occured. It happened to be a problem with the extUrl argument inside the ng-click function. I wrote it as {{vacature.url}} at first. But it should have been '{{vacature.url}} and now it works!

There was also a problem with using the options after declaring how the URL should be opened, so I left that out and now everything works properly :)